# What does this SSO error mean? - CTJSO1502E The authentication process to the configuration dashboard failed

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm just starting up with Bluemix Single Sign On (SSO). Whenever I'm accessing the SSO console using Safari I get a popup with the error below.

```
CTJSO1502E The authentication process to the configuration dashboard failed
```

I do not get this error when accessing the SSO console using my firefox browser.

I've already cleared the cache in Safari. Can anyone give me a pointer or something else to try to get past this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out the solution in Safari is that I needed to enable third-party cookies to access the SSO interface.

The iframe containing the SSO service dashboard comes to the overall Bluemix console **(.ng.bluemix.net)** from a host on a different DNS domain **(.iam.ibmcloudsecurity.com)**. Session cookies for the dashboard get blocked unless 3rd party cookies are allowed, or at least permitted from **.iam.ibmcloudsecurity.com**.